# Primefaces. AjaxStatus Dialog loads of behind the new dialog! What can this be?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, dialog, primefaces, loader

Pictures speak better than words:

[Dialog with problem (See picture because I don't have reputation to post here)](http://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-VBfD1_THND0/T7P6WAIXygI/AAAAAAAAAZg/K-gRgziHjjE/s983/dialogPrime2.png)

I have this AjaxStatus that shows this dialog with the message loading, this AjaxStatus is global to the application and responds to any existing flow ajax and it is working around the rest of the application but when you open the dialog of "visualizing cities (A specific dialog in a certain part of the system)" the new dialog opens on top of everything, even above the loader and it is very strange.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Sorry for my English, thanks for all. (Please send-me reputation for I can post images, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Is your ajax status dialog modal?

If not, just use a `<p:dialog modal="true" ...>`.

This will make your status dialog be on the top and adds an overlay to avoid clicks on other parts of the page.

Comment: Yes, my ajax status is and yet it stays that way... =/
I'm not undestand yet, when I have a little time I'll check to see if this really is a bug...